# How to list all the modified files in a shadow-volume?

Tags: windows, volume-shadow-service

When a Restore Point is created, Windows starts monitoring the volume and any changes are recorded in a proprietory diff file inside System Volume Information folder.

Thorough VSS-SDK api, we can expose the volume, but it shows us the whole volume and all the files/folders which have or have-not been modified since snapshot creation, and on access to any file, a filter-driver applies the diff, if required, and shows us the file.

My Question: Is it possible to list all the modified files, with respect to a restore point (except the brute-force method to compare each file inside the shadow-volume and the main-volume)?

How does Windows do it when we click on the previous versions tab in a file's Properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way IS brute-force, coupled with USN number-comparison For reference, the link to a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591842/how-to-compare-2-volumes-and-list-modified-files)

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the [NTFS Change Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal). Windows logs all changes to all files on an NTFS volume in a journal database (if the journal is on). This can be queried to return all changes from a specific start USN number (your restore point)

Here is [an article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx) about the journal that helped me a lot while implementing change journal functionality

Comment: thanks for the link,  would you know how to get the USN number for the restore point?  I"m struggling to get this info and have a unanswered question if you have a second?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544433/how-to-get-the-nextusn-journal-entry-for-a-vss-snapshot

Comment: I've added an answer to your question... Although it may not be exactly what you are looking for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To detect changes in the current file system vs a shadow copy, you can use a third party software like WinMerge with the shadow copy UNC paths
http://winmerge.org/. This will provide a GUI for comparisons

For example, use "C:\", vs "\localhost\C$\@GMT-2017.08.24-18.07.46"

Of course, enter a valid UNC path to coincide with the date and time of a shadow copy.

Answer (score -1):

Windows know from the attributes date modified. It compares the the two file and checks the modified date.

Comment: The date attributes (all three- creation,modified and access) can be easily modified programatically, so I don't think that's the case.